# Does Netbeans have export option like TortoiseSVN?

Tags: macos, svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn

I'm reading [how to use SVN on Netbeans here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780596527938/setting-up-version-control-using-subversion/i_sect12_d1e13512)

However, I can't find how to export a project (only code without .svn or .metadata) on Netbeans.

How to do that on Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while, I found that the export feature is a brand new feature and it has been recently implemented.

Now, I can export the project by right click on the project > Subversion > Copy > Export

Answer (score 1):

You can't do [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) via the user interface of Netbeans IDE. Use command-line or [GUI client like TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html) for this task.

**Update:** see @AtthaponJunpun-eak's answer. It seems that the `svn export` feature is now implemented in Netbeans.

Comment: That's sad.

Can you help recommend any alternative of TortoiseSVN because I'm using MAC OS ?

Comment: The closest one was SCPlugin http://scplugin.tigris.org/ but it looks like it's not under development anymore. All other clients I remember do not plug into Finder. I suggest checking the thread and trying out those clients for yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899/best-subversion-client-for-mac-os